# Подключить .htaccess с домена на поддомен

Tags: php, .htaccess

Описание:

Есть основной домен site.com и поддомен account.site.com (папки находятся в одной и той же директории)

На основном домене в корне лежит файл .htaccess с основными настройками

Задача:

Как подключить файл .htaccess на поддомен с основного домена? Я конечно могу его просто скопировать но хотелось бы использовать один файл .htaccess для всех поддоменов.

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: В контексте домашнего каталога сайта `account.site.com` установить директиву `AllowOverride All`

Comment: не понял, объясните подробней пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName account.site.com

    ... другие директивы ....

    <Directory /path/to/account.site.com/home/html>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ... другие директивы ....    

</VirtualHost>
```

Если у вас есть похожее описание виртуального домена, то добавьте в контекст его корневой директории директиву `AllowOverride All`. Апач будет знать, что надо искать файл `.htaccess` и "исполнять" его.